# Is there a way to solve this Docker Exception?

Tags: docker

I tried to solve this but can't do it.

Here is exception text :

```
    Docker.Core.Backend.BackendQuitException: Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS. See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization
       en Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoCheckPreconditionsAsync>d__31.MoveNext() en C:\workspaces\PR-15906\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:línea 307
    --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
       en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       en Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() en C:\workspaces\PR-15906\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:línea 29
    --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
       en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       en Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() en C:\workspaces\PR-15906\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:línea 62
    --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
       en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       en Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.<StartAsync>d__14.MoveNext() en C:\workspaces\PR-15906\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:línea 69
    --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
       en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       en Docker.Engines.Engines.<StartAsync>d__21.MoveNext() en C:\workspaces\PR-15906\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\Engines.cs:línea 114
    --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
       en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       en Docker.Core.TaskExtension.<Forget>d__0.MoveNext() en C:\workspaces\PR-15906\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Extensions.cs:línea 30
    --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
       en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Please highlight the code and press Ctrl-K so the code formats neatly. Here, white space and new lines are not shown unless you wrap a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the steps listed here ? https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization

Enabling Virtualization in bios is required, for which you will need to enter the BIOS menu by restarting and hitting F10, F2, F12, F1, or DEL ( Depends on manufacturer ).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, You have to enable the Hyper-V role on windows. Follow these steps for that,

1. Select Programs and Features on the right under related settings.
2. Select Turn Windows Features on or off.
3. Select Hyper-V and then click OK.

[image]

Hope your problem will solve!!